# How do I remove diacritics from a string in dynamics ax

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++, aot

I'm trying to convert some strings, I'd like to be able to remove diacritics from  strinf. (Exemple : éùèà would become euea)
i have try this :

```
   static str AALRemoveDiacritics( System.String input )
    {
        int i;
    System.Text.NormalizationForm    FormD;
    str normalizedString = input.Normalize(FormD);
    System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
 
    for (i = 0; i < strLen(normalizedString); i++)
        {
        System.Char c = normalizedString[i];
        if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            {
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
            }
        }
 
    return stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you tried making [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/410074/Removing-Diacritics-from-Strings) work in X++ and were very close.

Here's a working job I just wrote you can use:

```
static void AlexRemoveDiacritics(Args _args)
{
    str strInput = 'ÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉàáâãäåèéêëìíîïòóôõ£ALEX';
    System.String input = strInput;
    str retVal;
    int i;

    System.Char c;
    System.Text.NormalizationForm FormD = System.Text.NormalizationForm::FormD;
    str normalizedString = input.Normalize(FormD);
    System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    for (i = 0; i <= strLen(normalizedString); i++)
    {
        c = System.Char::Parse(subStr(normalizedString, i, 1));

        if (System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo::GetUnicodeCategory(c) != System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory::NonSpacingMark)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }

    input = stringBuilder.ToString();
    input = input.Normalize();
    retVal = input;

    info(strFmt("Before: '%1'", strInput));
    info(strFmt("After: '%1'", retVal));
}
```